# JAXB unmarshal: ignore xsi:nil=true

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using jaxb to write a client for a web service.  It works fine, except for one problem.  The XML I get back from the service has some elements with xsi:nil=true, but the element contains a value.  For example `<A xsi:nil="true">not blank</A>`.  This is probably a bug with the web service, but I don't know if I'll be able to get them to fix it.  The unmarshaller is giving me null for everything with xsi:nil=true, even when there is a value there.  Is there a way to tell the unmarshaller to ignore xsi:nil=true?

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack to work around the problem.  It works, but it's ugly.  I used a DOM parser to parse the XML, then programmatically removed the xsi:nil attributes where xsi:nil=true.  Then unmarshalled from the DOM.